# Which one is better to use, Need or Needs?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I have two sentences

```
does this item need to be repaired?
```

and

```
does this item needs to be repaired?
```

which sentence is better, and why.

Thank you.

Comment: "Does this item needS to be repaired is incorrect?"  You remove the "s" on the verb in a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "better" sentence because the second one breaks the rule. 
A question for the third person in present simple starts with "Does" which means a verb shouldn't have "-s" ("-es") ending.

*This item need**s** to be repaired.

Do**es** this item need(no ending) to be repaired?*

Answer (score 1):

As your sentence belongs to  `Present Indefinite` according to the grammar rules of English.

You should follow `Present Indefinite` the grammar rule while creating a question.

As per the English grammar rule for `Present Indefinite` your first sentence is correct.

```
Does this item need to be repaired?
```

[Reference Link](https://www.learngrammar.net/a/examples-of-present-indefinite-tense)